# Pattern match with "+" sign

Tags: pattern-matching, recursion

Can you pattern match with a "+" sign?

Here is the recursion...(which does not work)

```
Pr2[i_ + j_, 0] := (λ/(λ + μ))^(i + j)
Pr2[i_ + j_, j_] := (((i + j) - j + 1)/j)*((1 - λ/(λ + μ))/(λ/(λ + μ)))*Pr2[i + j, j - 1];
```

The original recursion is:

```
Pr1[n_, 0] := (λ/(λ + μ))^n
Pr1[n_, j_] := ((n - j + 1)/j)*((1 - λ/(λ + μ))/(λ/(λ + μ)))*Pr2[n, j - 1];
```

which does work.

I just want to be able to substitute $i+j$ for $n$ in the recursion.

==============================

Here are some examples of function calls and output

${\bf The\ function\ that\ works}$:

$$\mbox{Pr1}[35, 10] = \frac{183579396 \lambda ^{25} \left(1-\frac{\lambda    }{\lambda +\mu }\right)^{10}}{(\lambda +\mu )^{25}}$$

$$\mbox{Pr1}[4, 2] = \frac{6 \lambda ^2 \left(1-\frac{\lambda }{\lambda +\mu }\right)^2}{(\lambda +\mu )^2}$$

$\bf{So...for\ the\ new\ function}$...

$$\mbox{Pr2}[2 + 2, 2] = \mbox{Pr1}[4, 2]$$

$$\mbox{Pr2}[25 + 10, 10] = \mbox{Pr1}[35, 10]$$

$\bf{I\ also\ tried}$...

```
Pr2[Plus[i_, j_], 0] := (\[Lambda]/(\[Lambda] + \[Mu]))^Plus[i, j];
Pr2[Plus[i_, j_], i_] := (Plus[i, j] - i + 1)/
   i (1 - \[Lambda]/(\[Lambda] + \[Mu]))/(\[Lambda]/(\[Lambda] + \
\[Mu])) Pr2[Plus[i, j], i - 1];
```

But the result is...

```
(3 (\[Lambda] + \[Mu]) (1 - \[Lambda]/(\[Lambda] + \[Mu])) Pr2[4, 
  1])/(2 \[Lambda])
```

which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, you can pattern match on Plus. But why do you want to? If i & j are numbers, then `i + j` will resolve to a number and won't match the Plus. If you pass a Plus expression with undefined symbols, that will match the Plus, but it also would have matched the `n_`, so I'm not sure what you gain. You could play around with various Hold* attributes, but without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to suggest anything.

Comment: What's a typical function call and expected output?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I gave some examples - thanks...

Comment: @lericr Because I can code this in .Net and don't understand why I can't do the same in Mathematica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[Pr2]
```

Give `Pr2` the attribute [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html)

```
SetAttributes[Pr2, HoldFirst]

Pr2[i_ + j_, 0] := (λ/(λ + μ))^(i + j)
Pr2[i_ + j_, j_] := (((i + j) - j + 1)/j)*
     ((1 - λ/(λ + μ))/(λ/(λ + μ)))*Pr2[i + j, j - 1];

Pr2[2 + 2, 2]

(* (3 (λ + μ) (1 - λ/(λ + μ)) Pr2[2 + 2, 1])/(2 λ) *)
```

Note that the second definition requires the second argument to be the same as one of the summands; consequently, `Pr2[2+2, 1]` cannot evaluate.

Decouple the second argument from the summands

```
ClearAll[Pr2]

SetAttributes[Pr2, HoldFirst]

Pr2[i_ + j_, 0] := (λ/(λ + μ))^(i + j)
Pr2[i_ + j_, k_] := (((i + j) - k + 1)/k)*
     ((1 - λ/(λ + μ))/(λ/(λ + μ)))*Pr2[i + j, k - 1];

Pr2[2 + 2, 2]

(* (6 λ^2 (1 - λ/(λ + μ))^2)/(λ + μ)^2 *)

Pr2[25 + 10, 10]

(* (183579396 λ^25 (1 - λ/(λ + μ))^10)/(λ + μ)^25 *)
```